# Firebase prevent sorting by key on insertion

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have an android application where I am looping over a LinkedHashMap and setting values under a firebase path but it seems that firebase orders the keys alphabetically, whereas I want firebase to keep keys in the order in which they are inserted under a location

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : itemList.entrySet())
{
    Log.v("itemlist", entry.getKey());
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();

    // now work with key and value...
    mItemsReference.child(itemName).child(key).setValue(value);
}
```

If I have entries such as Name,Price,Description in itemList which is a LinkedHashMap then on running the above code I have nodes in the following order - Description,Name,Price i.e alphabetically instead of in the order in which they were inserted. Is there any way I can maintain the insertion order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase is a JSON database. The order of keys in a JSON object is unspecified. But Firebase (as most JSON serializers) by default shows the keys in alphabetical order. If you need the keys in a specific order, you should use either use keys that maintain that order (e.g. [using Firebase push IDs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data)) or [retrieve the items with a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up using the setPriority method with an incrementing counter for each field to force firebase to store the keys in the order in which they were inserted